# Error message (Column count doesn't match value count at row 1)

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I am currently trying to insert the values in the database table, the database that I have created shows like this:

```
recipeid - int (Primary key) NOT NULL
recipename - varchar(80)
reciperating - int
recipephoto - longtext
```

However, when I try to issue the sql statement as shown below:

`(insert into userRecipeInfo values('Fried rice',4,'https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/03734ee186eba543fb3d0e35db2a90a14a5d79e3/0_173_5200_3120/master/5200.jpg?width=1200&height=900')`

The error message shows this instead:

```
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

I would like to know on what caused this error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your INSERT statement provides 3 values, but your table has 4 columns. You need to qualify the target columns - which is highly recommended even if you do provide values for all columns.

```
insert into userRecipeInfo 
  (recipename, reciperating, recipephoto ) 
values
  ('Fried rice',4,'https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/03734ee186eba543fb3d0e35db2a90a14a5d79e3/0_173_5200_3120/master/5200.jpg?width=1200&height=900')
```

Comment: Hmm, it states "Field 'recipeid' doesn't have a default value"

Comment: @Jtang11: well, then you need to provide a value

Comment: It states this "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`userinfo`.`userrecipeinfo`, CONSTRAINT `userrecipeinfo_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`recipeid`) REFERENCES `accountinfo` (`id`))"

Answer (score 0):

Because your table has 4 columns, but you only pass 3 values.
With an insert statement it is always best to specify the column names:

```
insert into userRecipeInfo (recipename ,reciperating ,recipephoto ) 
values('Fried rice',4,'https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/03734ee186eba543fb3d0e35db2a90a14a5d79e3/0_173_5200_3120/master/5200.jpg?width=1200&height=900)
```

And hope that recipeid gets autogenerated.

The advantage of specifying the column names:

- if your schema changes in the future and you add a nullable column, the statement will not break
- if the database is recreated and the order of columns change, there is no problem if you have specified the matching column names in the statement.